# How to define the colorbar of my plot manually

Tags: plotting, color, legending

Let's say I have an arbitrary plot, for example a plot of a finite points that I colored them by my own taste independent of any formula like $f(x,y)$ or density etc. Or I have several plots and then I use the `Show` command to display them in the same plot. Now I want to add a colorbar, of course I have to use the `BarLegend` option. But now here is what I couldn't get from the help pages of Mathematica. How can I tell Mathematica that I want my colorbar starts from a specific color and ends to a specific color and varies in between the way I specify. For example I want to force it to be defined by `RGBColor[i,0,1-i]` where i is varying from 0 to 1 and then I also want to have different numbers than 0 and 1 as minimum and maximum numbers in the colorbar. My main problem is to tell colorbar to vary according to `RGBColor[i,0,1-i]`. In the help pages they refer to each other, BarLegend to ColorFunction and from there to some others and it is confusing to me. The examples listed there also use predefined color gradients such as visible, hue, etc. What about I just simply want to have a function like `i->RGBColor[i,0,1-i]` or maybe later a piecewise defined function that varies the same way I described but between several colors. I guess it shouldn't be something complicated, but anyway the help pages made me more confused. Thanks for any help.

Comment: does something like `minmax = {.3, .9};
BarLegend[{RGBColor[#, 0, 1 - #] &, minmax}]`  or `BarLegend[{RGBColor[#, 0, 1 - #] &@Rescale[#, minmax] &, minmax}]` give what you need?

Comment: You may also be interested in `Blend`.

Comment: @C.E. and kglr thanks to both of you, yes both are producing what I want :)

Comment: @C.E.Using `BarLegend[{Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, {0.13, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}, #] &, {0, 0.13}}]` alone is working fine, but `ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {1/4, 4/5}, {1, 0}}, PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 1], PointSize[0.02]], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, {0.13, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}},#] &, {0, 0.13}}]]` has a problem in color scaling. Do you know why?

Comment: @C.E. I also don't get any colorbar when adding the BarLegend in Show for a list of plots, i.e. `Show[plist, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, {0.13, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}},#] &, {0, 0.13}}]]` :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer the questions in your comments. First question, why the scaling is different when `BarLegend` is used inside `ListPlot` and separately. The documentation does not say much about this, other than a very vague remark in the Scope -> PlotLegends section of the `BarLegend` documentation page:

> BarLegend automatically picks up values of ColorFunction and
> ColorFunctionScaling

So there is an interplay between `BarLegend` and plotting functions, although it isn't clearly described exactly how it works.

In any case, this example shows what is happening:

```
BarLegend[{
  Blend[{
     {0, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]},
     {0.13^2, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}
     }, #] &,
  {0, 0.13}
  }]
```

[image: Example]

This output matches what the bar legend looks like inside `ListPlot`. Consequently, what is happening is that when you first say that the domain of the bar legend is [0, 0.13] and then also say that the color function should blend between 0 and 0.13, the result is that the color is blended over [0, 0.13^2].

A simple way to avoid this is to not specify the scaling both in `BarLegend` and in `Blend`:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {1/4, 4/5}, {1, 0}};
cf = Blend[{
     RGBColor[0, 0, 1],
     RGBColor[1, 0, 0]
     }, #] &;
ListPlot[
 pts,
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf, {0, 0.13}}]
 ]
```

[image: Example]

Another way is to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` because then it seems that the independence of `BarLegend` against `ListPlot` is regained:

```
cf = Blend[{
     {0, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]},
     {0.13, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}
     }, #] &;
ListPlot[
 pts,
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf, {0, 0.13}}]
 ]
```

[image: Example]

As for the example with `PlotLegends` in `Show`, I'm not sure that this is supported. The arguments acceptable to `Show` are, at least generally speaking, those acceptable to `Graphics`, and I don't see `PlotLegends` among the options in the documentation for `Graphics`. Furthermore, it might be that since the plot range, image padding, image margins etc. are determined by the argument of `Show`, any subsequently added plot legend might appear out of view. However, I tried playing with those options and so far as I can tell this is not the case. The best solution is probably to stick your plot legend into a plot.

Comment: Thanks for your complete and nice explanation. For the second part, Adding the colorbar to only one of the plots in the list and then using Show will provide what I want (adding to show doesn't work, adding to each plot will create many colorbars to the result of Show, but adding to only one of them, will give the expected result). Thanks again for your help.:)